# How substr function works?

Tags: php, string, substr

I have come across this code in php.net.

```
<?php
echo substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
echo substr('abcdef', 1, 3);  // bcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 4);  // abcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
echo substr('abcdef', -1, 1); // f

// Accessing single characters in a string
// can also be achieved using "square brackets"
$string = 'abcdef';
echo $string[0];                 // a
echo $string[3];                 // d
echo $string[strlen($string)-1]; // f

?>
```

`substr('abcdef',1,3)` returns `'bcd'`, the last index is 3 and it returns `"bcd"` and if I do `substr('abcdef',0,4)` returns `'abcd'`. But I expected `substr('abcdef',0,3)` to return `'abcd'` as compared to the first example. What am I missing here.

How `substr($string,$start,$last)` works in php?

**EDIT:** Sorry every body I thought 3rd param is not length and something beyond my understanding...due to my `Java` background sorry. Thanks for all comments and answers.

Comment: Where did you get $last from? The third parameter is length. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: @Wooble I totally got it now.... thanks :)

Comment: `substr` works like described [here](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)

Comment: I thought 3rd param is not length and something beyond my understanding...due to my `Java` background sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`substr()` is NOT `substr($string, $start, $last)` it's `substr($string, $start, $length)`. So `substr('abcdef', 0, 4)` returns `abcd` because it starts at 0 (a) and it goes for 4 letters.

Also random note: `echo substr('abcdef', -1, 1);` is inherently redundant since -1 only has a length of 1 so the string might as well be: `echo substr('abcdef', -1);`

Comment: your answer will be accepted thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

The first integer tells the position where to start the search, the second one tells the length. In your case 4 characters (start from 0).

Answer (score 0):

`substr('abcdef',0,3)` will give an output of `abc`
To get an output `abcd` you should use `substr('abcdef',0,4)`

`substring` works as `substr('abcdef',start_position,no. of character you want)`
so if you want any substring starting from the first character, you should use 0 as start_position.

You can refer to this [`link`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp).

Comment: @pinkpanther Its fine. I was just editing my answer.