# How to get all TD values via PHP and String functions

Tags: php, string, parsing, substr

I need to get data from TD, and the variable is a string:

```
$string='<tr><td>abc</td><td>def</td><td>ghi</td></tr>';
echo $td_num = substr_count($string, '<td>');
for ($i=0;$i<$td_num;$i++)
{
echo "<br /><br />".$i."<br />";

$first_td[$i] = strpos($string, '<td>');
echo 'First position: '.$first_td[$i]."<br />"; 

$last_td[$i]=strpos($string, "</td>");
echo 'Last position: '.$last_td[$i]."<br />";

$td_value[$i]=substr($string,$first_td[$i],$last_td[$i]);

echo "TD Value: ".$td_value[$i]."<br />";   
echo $string_size = strlen($string)."<br />";

$string = substr($string,$last_td[$i]);
}
```

Result is :

```
       3

       0
       First position: 4
       Last position: 11
       TD Value: abc45


       1
       First position: 5
       Last position: 0
       TD Value: 
       34


       2
       First position: 5
       Last position: 0 
       TD Value: 
       34
```

Tell me please, why is it not working? How can I make it work? How can parse the TD values differently?

Comment: google://php simplexml

Comment: Use an HTML parser library, like [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Barmar any reason you would pick that one instead of SimpleXML or DOMDocument where both come shipped with PHP?

Comment: `substr()` takes a length as the third parameter, not another position.

Comment: @Prix I like that it uses selector syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Anyone who would bother a little about it would find that XPath is an infinitely more powerful concept :)

Comment: You must modify the last statement to: $string = substr($string,$last_td[$i] + strlen("</td>"));

Comment: @Jack I just picked on that I happened to be familiar with. It was just an example, not a strong recommendation. I've never had to write any PHP code that uses an HTML parser, so I'm not intimately familiar with the pros and cons of each. The important thing is to not do the parsing by hand -- which library to choose is less important decision.

Comment: @Barmar That, I think, we can all agree upon :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How substr function works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007089/how-substr-function-works)

Answer (score 4):

`DOMDocument` can also be used with this:

```
$string = '<tr><td>abc</td><td>def</td><td>ghi</td></tr>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td) {
    echo $td->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

You can get td values with this: (Output sample)

abc 
def 
ghi

Answer (score 1):

Consider simpledom, [link here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It would work something like this in your case:

```
$html = str_get_html($string);
foreach ($html->find('td') as $td)
    echo $td->innertext."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Found \o/**

( im not very good at english so maybe its not understandable, but well, at least, the code works :P )

In fact you are giving substr a wrong 3rd argument as said @Jack (it should be the length of the cut, so you have to substract first pos to last pos), you had also pos probs, beceause what you search for have a length and you have to take it in count to get only the content of the TDs `<td>` is 4 char long, and `</td>` is 5 ; So you had to add +4 to the first pos to get the start of the content position, and add 5 to the last_td in the after process substr to remove the end `</td>`.

The code below works properly :

```
$string='<tr><td>abc</td><td>def</td><td>ghi</td></tr>';

echo $td_num = substr_count($string, '<td>');

for ($i=0;$i<$td_num;$i++)
{
    echo "<br /><br />".$i."<br />";

    $first_td[$i] = strpos($string, '<td>') + 4; 
    $last_td[$i]  = strpos($string, '</td>');
    $td_value[$i] = substr($string,$first_td[$i],$last_td[$i]-$first_td[$i]);

    echo 'First position: '.$first_td[$i].'<br />';
    echo 'Last position:  '.$last_td[$i] .'<br />';
    echo 'TD Value: '.htmlentities($td_value[$i]).'<br />';   
    echo $string_size = strlen($string).'<br />';

    $string = substr($string,$last_td[$i]+5);
}

var_dump($first_td, $last_td, $td_value, $string);
```

But if you don't need places of the  content, you can just use this one :

```
$string='<tr><td>abc</td><td>def</td><td>ghi</td></tr>';

$td_num = substr_count($string, '<td>');

for ($i=0;$i<$td_num;$i++)
{   
    $first_td = strpos($string, '<td>') + 4; 
    $last_td  = strpos($string, '</td>');
    $td_values[$i] = substr($string,$first_td,$last_td-$first_td);
    $string = substr($string,$last_td+5);

    echo 'TD Value ['.$i.'] => '.htmlentities($td_values[$i]).'<br />';
}

var_dump($td_values);
```

Or you can just use preg_match_all if your source is trusted one

```
$string='<tr><td>abc</td><td>def</td><TD>ghi</TD></tr>';

$matches = null;

if( preg_match_all('#<td>(.*)</td>#isU', $string, $matches) ){
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

- [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)
- [More about regexs](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: Well, fwiw, it does beat working with `substr()` and `strpos()` :)

Comment: It's just the answer for : 
_How can parse the TD values differently?_ ^^

Comment: +1 because you were the only one explaining why his code didn't work.